# select id from dropdown menu and inser into certain album with certain id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am still a beginner and I can't figure out how to, when user chooses an album from a dropdown menu (that I take from a database), get the ID from that album and put it in another table as value.
So I have two tables, albums and pictures, and I want to take the ID from "albums" and put it into "pictures".

Here is what I did:

```
<form action="addImg.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form2">
<label>Insert into:</label>  <select name="album" id="album">
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?> 
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . " " . $row["ime"] ?></option> 

<?php }
}
?>      
</select><br><br>
<input type="file" name="image" /><br><br>       
<br>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

So here I have a `select` control with options where its values are ID's from "albums" (I will have 4 albums, Wednesday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday), but how do I forward a certain ID into the pictures table?

```
$album = $_POST['album'];
$sqlAddUrl = "INSERT INTO pictures(url, album_id) VALUES ('$file_url', '$id_albumi')";
$result = $conn->query($sqlAddUrl);
```

So if the user chose Friday (id = 2) from dropdown menu I want to send that id into  "album_id".

I hope I explained my problem properly.

Comment: so, what is the error?

Comment: is it a _foreign key_ what you want? Take a look: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/foreign-keys/info)

Comment: @kirangadhvi I don't have an error, This question is more on how to do this, then looking for a specific answer. So point is that I want to have two identical columns in two tables.

Comment: @NachoM.Yes, that is maby point of this question.I'll start exploring.

Comment: @NachoM.I set it up as a foreign key, but now I am looking what is next, how to recognize selected choice from dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer on my question if someone needs it. 
First I set up my *FOREIGN KEY* so in both tables now I have two columns withs same names.

After that I use name from  name="album" and send it with POST metod **$album = $_POST['album'];**, and after that I made simple query:
**$sqlDodajUrl = "INSERT INTO slike (url, album_id) VALUES ('$file_url', '$album')";**

And send it to resoult **$result = $conn->query($sqlDodajUrl);**